# browser says server is offline

Tags: linux

I just ordered a server from serverdeals.org . I am having a weird problem that even support can't find out what is that

They gave me a raw server and i install nginx just as i wanted(its successful)
However when i went to `http://serverip/` , browsers says page not available(aka offline)

What could it be ...First time i am getting this 
Its definely not an installation error on my part as i have installed nginx on numerous servers till date

What can the server guys missed?
I can ssh and login via ftp fine though

UPDATE:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1184/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15847/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1503/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52888               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1202/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 :::45774                    :::*                        LISTEN      1202/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      1184/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1503/sshd
```

Comment: Run `netstat -nltp` and check of port 80 is listening.

Comment: I added response.....in my post

Comment: Like the post below, ensure your firewall allows port 80 access. What OS are you on?

Comment: I am in Centos 6.3 - Provided says he never installed centos 6 before , he only worked on centos 5

Comment: I once had a situation where this port was blocked by an iptables rule on a so called managed-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you actually started nginx:

```
service nginx start
```

Make sure you opened port 80 in the firewall:

```
system-config-firewall-tui   # (Red Hat/CentOS)
# (You're on your own for anything else)
```

Comment: Yes nginx has been started......no firewall install on system

Comment: edit u were right , i stop iptable and i was able to access port 80